# Proving a tautology in type theory

Tags: type-theory

I am trying to prove the tautology ((P->Q)xP)->Q in type theory, and I can't quite get started. Any help would be great.

Comment: What notation is that?  What does the "x" mean?

Comment: @Wildcard I assume it's supposed to be a $\times$, so that the whole type he wants to inhabit is $((P \to Q) \times P) \to Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term
\begin{align*}
  \lambda \operatorname{pair} : (P \to Q) \times P . (\operatorname{proj}_1 \operatorname{pair}) (\operatorname{proj}_2 \operatorname{pair})
\end{align*}
where $\operatorname{proj}_1$ and $\operatorname{proj}_2$ are the first and second projections of the Cartesian product "$\times$", respectively.